# Setup Raspberry Pi Bluetooth using Matlab

Tags: matlab, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I want to set up a built-in Bluetooth module of Raspberry pi for providing wifi SSID and Password using MATLAB. But I don't find any Bluetooth object in MATLAB to connect the raspberry pi Bluetooth. i used MATLAB raspbian Image os

I have tried to openShell command for setuping the bluetooth
OpenShell Command

```
sudo bluetoothctl
sudo discoverable on  %or
discoverable on
```

but i got this error:
Failed to set discoverable on:  org.bluez.Error.Failed